# Rails pass user object to another controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am building a Rails project where I have a user, and that user has many `Tests` (it's like a Trivia game). I have a `UsersController` where I query the user (going to implement login later).

In my view I have a button which "starts" the test. I need to associate the user with a test, because my `User has_many Tests` (user_id is a foreign key on tests). My question is, how do I pass my `@user` object to my `TestsController` so I can associate the created test with the logged in user?

Here is my `UsersController`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(1)
  end

  def start_test
    redirect_to tests_path
  end
end
```

In my users show view I have:

```
<p>Welcome <%= @user.name %>!</p>

<%= button_to "Start Test", users_start_test_path %>
```

When the button is clicked I redirect to `tests_path` which is in TestsController:

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController        
    def index
      # here I need to create the Test belonging to the user 
    end
end
```

I am new to Rails and don't know how to pass that `@user` to `TestsController` so I can create the test belonging to the user. Theoretically I don't even need the whole `@user`, just the `id`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should improve this by setting the route properly, Instead linking a controller action directly to another controller. I would create the following route.

```
resources :users do
  resources :tests
end
```

This will force you to always have a `user_id`. For your new tests path you get this. `new_user_test_path(@user)`

This will use basics CRUD actions. So to make a new test for the correct user, use the the `def new` action in the tests controller.

```
def new 
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]
  @new_test = @user.tests.new
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This worked great and makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

The controllers are standalone. They cann't share variables. You could try to send user id intro the request to controller TestsController (or better use an authentication system). Or directly in the TestsController calls User.find(1) again.

Answer (score 0):

The only variable you can pass between controllers is a parameter through the routing (or the session).

So you can have a HTML Form that passes a body to an action inside a different controller OR for what I see in your case by visiting a route and pass a friendly query string parameter, like an ID.

So you could:

```
<%= button_to "Start Test", users_start_test_path(user_id: @user.id) %>
```

And then in your TestController:

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController        
    def index
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to pass the current_user variable because it can then be hijacked.

This is how I would set the **TestsController**

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController        
    def index
      @tests = current_user.tests
    end
    
    def new
      @test = current_user.tests.new
    end

    def create
      current_user.tests.create(test_params)
    end

    def show
      @test = current_user.tests.find(params[:id]) # this will only find tests scoped to that user
    end

    def edit
      @test = current_user.tests.find(params[:id]) # this will only find tests scoped to that user

    end
    def update
      @test = current_user.tests.find(params[:id]) # this will only find tests scoped to that user
      @test.update(test_params)
    end    

    def test_params
      params.require(:test).permit()
    end

end
```

This way now you have the test scoped to the user.
I am assuming that you have device for user management